# Django Rest Framework - Upload file from HTML/JavaScript client

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a HTML/JavaScript client independent of Django (not created by Django Framework) and I need to upload files using the REST service created with Django Rest Framework (DRF). In the server side, I have a model with these fields:

```
class FileFicha(models.Model):
    Record = models.ForeignKey(Record)
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    File = models.FileField(upload_to='files/Record', blank=False)
    Upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Titulo
```

Now I can upload files using de DRF admin panel but I've tried to upload the files with an external client and I have not been able to replicate this.

I've tried to discover the HTML function of the POST button of the DRF admin panel (to simulate the same behavior in my client) but I could not find how the form is being sent. I think that it could be in a javascript function but I couldn't find it so any help regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check what the API's doing, use Firebug, it works a lot better than the Chrome inspector to check network messages, it can help you figure out exactly what it's sending to the backend.

With respect to how to upload files, it really depends on what you're doing in the client. If you're sending the information using AJAX, you probably need to send it using a FormData object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).